# Checking if a global variable exists and removing it

Tags: python

To check if a global variable exists (and if so, delete it) I have been using this method:

```
if 'y' in globals():
     y.remove()
```

But I get the following error:

`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

This method has worked for me in the past, I don't understand why the if statement accepts the statement as true, which implies 'y' exists, and then tells me 'y' does not exist. Is there a fix or even a completely different method of doing this? For context, 'y' is part of a scatter plot on a matplotlib.figure plot, which is embedded in a canvas for a tkinter GUI.

Comment: I am assuming `y` a list that is why you are getting that error. `remove` is an attribute for lists in python

Comment: @Matiiss ignore me, ucczs is correct :)

Comment: Just as a side-note - if you are learning Python I would suggest avoiding `global` altogether. I has it's use-cases, but too often it is a shortcut that will bite you later.

Comment: @alex `global` or `globals`?

Comment: @Matiiss both actually. Learn the scopes first, then fiddle with `global`/`globals()`

Comment: @alex I usually try and avoid global variables but for this specific project they have proved to the easier method unfortunately

Comment: Sure, let me just link this answer _[Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/1185254)_ for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to delete a variable you should use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del):

```py
if 'y' in globals():
    del y
```

Comment: This stopped the error, however it does not remove ```y``` from the scatter graph like before and I get duplicates

Comment: Ok weirdly the solution is to use ```del y``` for part of my code but keep ```y.remove()``` for other parts, so thank you for the solution.